# Where to put business logic?

Tags: sql, database, logic

As the title suggests, I'm pondering whereabouts in my app to put some business logic and would be interested in some opinions. It is a simple app which downloads pages from the web and stores them in a sqlite database.

Business logic dictates that the app can only store one entry for a particular URL. I have set up the database so URLs have to be unique and currently rely on this to enforce the logic. I.e. if an attempt is made to insert a web page which is already stored, an error code is returned from the database and the user is informed.

However, I can't help feeling that the 'app layer' (java code) should know about this rule too - it doesn't feel right to rely on an sql error code for this.

I think I have three options:

1 have the database enforce the logic

2 have the app layer enforce the logic and remove the unique constraint on the database

3 have the logic in both places

No 2 is the least desirable to me as the database would not be in control of its own integrity. No 3 would require some duplication, but would mean the same database could be used in other apps and its integrity would be intact.

Would love to hear some views on this.

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app layer should enforce the logic. This is just easier for design. Database does data things and business logic layer (app layer) does the logic. Keep things separated and make your life simpler since when you need to change a data thing you change it in the database and any logic changes get changed in the app layer. This is sort of a highly debated topic so be prepared to receive different answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looks like you got there in the nick of time!

Comment: Yeah some people will mark this as not constructive but the thing is that they either consider it basic or too opinionated to make a difference. Personally this is how I do it but I've had people tell me that logic in the database is fine but to each his own I guess. It's just easier to separate things.

Comment: Took me ages to type that out on my phone as well :-|